# How to enable PWA in vite application using react?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, vite-plugin-pwa

I have installed vite-plugin-pwa and changed my vite.config.js file like this. I cannot see the service worker in application tab in chrome

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import {VitePWA} from "vite-plugin-pwa";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    VitePWA({
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      injectRegister: 'auto',
      manifest: {
        // caches the assets/icons mentioned (assets/* includes all the assets present in your src/ directory)
        includeAssets: ["favicon.ico", "apple-touch-icon.png", "assets/*"],
        name: 'Simplifying Progressive Web App (PWA) Development with Vite: A Beginners Guide',
        short_name: 'PWA Guide',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        theme_color: '#000000',
        icons: [
          {
            src: '/images/icon.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: '/images/icon.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png'
          }
        ]
      },
      workbox: {
        // defining cached files formats
        globPatterns: ["**/*.{js,css,html,ico,png,svg,webmanifest}"],
      }
    }),
  ],
});
```

I was expecting that when i will integrate the package i will see the service worker in application tab and also an option to download the app on mobile device and also on desktop